# Hibernate session.update() vs update query?

Tags: java, hibernate

Hi if want to update some specific columns of a row so should i use an update query in hibernate or simply use the `session.update()` method of hibernate. Just came to know about

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(
        dynamicUpdate = true
```

annotation if set i can update specific columns. I haven't used this before so just want to know if there are any norms of using this or not. Just need your help on making a decision on this. Which approach will be better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With dynamic session update off, Hibernate will cache all of possible queries **for all entities**. So Hibernate doesn't have to generate SQL each time it wants to update an entity.

When it's on, Hibernate will always generate SQL queries when requested, instead of caching it. So it's lighter for your database, but it becomes heavier for Hibernate.

When should you use Hibernate Dynamic Update ? If you have a huge table with tons of columns, caching all queries for all entities will cost much more memory than usual. So you could turn dynamic update on to improve performance. Also, if you are debugging, dynamic update will give you more readable queries because only modified column will appear in your update statement.

Should you use update queries or session update ? Update queries are less readable and harder to maintain (for instance if a field name has changed, you have to change all your queries whereas session update won't be impacted).